# Find repetition misprint in a text with regex

Tags: regex

Is it possibile to find all the repetition misprints in a text (in my case a LaTeX source), for example:

```
... The Lagrangian that that includes this potential ...
... This is confimided by the the theorem of ...
```

using regex?

Use your favourite tool (sed, grep) / language (python, perl, ...)

Comment: [Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo).

Comment: The programmer had had success using a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using back references with `egrep -w` and the regexp `(\w+)\s+\1` :

```
$ echo "The Lagrangian that that includes this potential" | egrep -ow "(\w+)\s\1"
that that

$ echo "This is confimided by the the theorem of" | egrep -ow "(\w+)\s+\1"
the the
```

Note: the `-o` option displays the only part of the line that matches which is useful for demonstrating what is actually matched, you probably want to drop that option and use `--color` instead. The `-w` option is important to match whole words only otherwise `is is` would match in `This is con..`.

```
(\w+) # Matches & captures one or more word characters ([A-Za-z0-9_])
\s+   # Match one or more whitespace characters 
\1    # The last captured word
```

Using  `egrep -w --color "(\w+)\s+\1" file` has the benefit that potential wrong repeated words are clearly highlighted, a substitution probably isn't wise as many correct example such  as `reggae raggae sauce` or `beautiful beautiful day` would be changed.

Comment: Your regex would match "Tha sand and sea"

Comment: @Bohemian did you read my answer? The `-w` option of `grep` is important here. My solution would not match your example nor `This is..` in the OP examples.

Comment: OK, but does it not also match "iPhone and android"?

Comment: @Bohemian **No** as clearly stated in my answer, in the comment on my answer and in the comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This JavaScript example works:

```
var s = '... The Lagrangian that that includes this potential ... This is confimided by the the theorem of ...'
var result = s.match(/\b(\w+)\s\1\b/gi)
```

Result:

```
["that that", "the the"];
```

The Regex:

```
/\s(\w+)\s\1/gi

# /     --> Regex start,
# \b    --> A word boundary,
# (\w+) --> Followed by a word, grouped,
# \s    --> Followed by a space,
# \1    --> Followed by the word in group 1,
# \b    --> Followed by a word boundary,
# /gi   --> End regex, (g)lobal flag, case (i)nsensitive flag.
```

The word boundaries are added to prevent the regex from matching strings like `"hot hotel"` or `"nice ice"`

Comment: Your regex would match "Tha sand and sea"

Comment: @Bohemian: I noticed, fixing. **Edit:** fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grep -E '\b(\w+)\s+\1\b'  myfile.txt
```

Comment: Just curious: What's `\b`?

Comment: @Cerbrus `\b` stands for a word boundary.

Comment: Which can be achieved by using the grep's `-w` option - `force PATTERN to match only whole words`

Comment: Oh, that's nice, that's just what I needed! Didn't know about those :P

Comment: You are using ER features here so you answer don't work as is!

Comment: @sudo_O isn't that what the -E option is for?

Comment: @Bohemian yes it is, before your edit you was using `-e` not `-E` which is `use PATTERN for matching`

Answer (score 0):

An example in Python to show how to remove a duplicate word:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s1 = '... The Lagrangian that that includes this potential ...'

In [3]: s2 = '... This is confimided by the the theorem of ...'

In [4]: regex = r'\b(\w+)\s+\1\b'

In [5]: re.sub(regex, '\g<1>', s1)
Out[5]: '... The Lagrangian that includes this potential ...'

In [6]: re.sub(regex, '\g<1>', s2)
Out[6]: '... This is confimided by the theorem of ...'
```

Comment: You need to respect word boundaries, notice the word `is` gets removed in `s2`.

Comment: @sudo_O Yes, I just realized and fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Good, however blindly substituting might not be the best option as you could remove false positives, there are many acceptable cases of repeating words.

Comment: @sudo_O I know, from a linguistic point of view it's not a good idea. But I'm sure the OP knows about that.

Comment: thank you, by the way I think that removing duplicate word automatically is too dangerous, sometimes they are correct: "the decay into gamma gamma couple"